# How to read this List?

Tags: list, haskell

My apologies if my question is not well worded but I seem to have a lack of words to specifically ask.

I found a line that results in a list of all multiples of three from 1 to 1000 while searching for Haskell learning rescources. I understand what this line does, it is not too difficult to see evaluated in GHCi.

```
[n | n <- [1..1000], n `rem` 3 == 0]
```

My actual problem is i do not know how to read this line in plain englisch and how exactly the list is generated and what `n | n <- [1..1000]` means.
Can this be read similar to a for loop?

Such an expression was not covered in the basic tutorials I read. Where can I find documentation that is to be considered beginners read and covers how to plain read expressions?

It would greatly improve my learing process if I actually had some vocabulary describing what I type there ;)

Comment: Learn You a Haskell For Great Good has a section on this towards the start of the book - http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension

Comment: Fun stuff. I knew of it but did start with Real World Haskell that covers it pretty late around page 280 after a lot of different examples that include lists as well. Now i do not really understand why as this is a great way to generate specific lists.

Comment: btw, that notation is inspired by the so-called [set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[n | n <- [1..1000], n `rem` 3 == 0]
```

is called a [list comprehension](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension). It can basically be read as: "List of n, where n is in range 1 to 1000 and n remainder 3 == 0".

Comment: List comprehension was the term missing. Now i know what to look for. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`[n | n <- [1..1000], n`rem`3 == 0]` is the list of all `n` such that `n` is in `[1 .. 1000]` and `` n `rem` 3 == 0 ``.

It's meant to read similarly to set notation (i.e. `{n | n ∈ (1..1000), n ≡ 0 mod 3}`).

Comment: Thank you for the "translation".